# Can someone help break down this sentence? 僕が同一人物だと確信に踏み切れないのはこの子の顔が半分しか見えていないからだ

Tags: grammar, parsing, cleft-sentences

[image]

I don't really understand this sentence. Could someone help break it down for me?

> 僕が同一人物だと確信に踏み切れないのはこの子の顔が半分しか見えていないからだ。

From the way I interpreted it, it would have a meaning similar to:

> The reason I can't boldly believe she is the same person is because I can't see more than half of her face.

which I do not think is correct.

Comment: It looks like you should be asking specifically about the 〜〜に踏み切る part.

Comment: Why do you think it is not correct ?

Comment: Without more context, no one would be able to tell how correct or incorrect your TL is.  For instance, I could not tell who it is that is being unable to 確信に踏み切る or who it is that can only see half of この子's face.  (And I am a native Japanese-speaker! )  You should keep reminding yourself that Japanese is a most contextual language.  By providing more context, you would always receive a better answer and do so more quickly as well.

Comment: I think 確信に踏み切れない is almost the same meaning as the sentence like 確信が持てない、確信がない、確信しきれない.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm an 82-year-old Japanese male.

I will translate the quoted part as:

> The reason I'm not confident of her being the same girl is that I can see only half (portion) of her face.

Answer (score -1):

For what's worth the sentence is not grammatical because you can't say "確信に踏み切れない". You have to say "確信しきれない", meaning that you aren't quite able to be 100% sure.

I'd translate it as:

> The reason I can't be 100% sure she is the same person is because I can only see half of her face

Comment: 「確信に踏み切る」という言い方は「思い切って確信する」と同様に若干不自然だとは感じますが (「さあ、これから確信しよう」と自分で選んでする行為ではないので)、それを not grammatical だと言われると、「不自然なだけで、間違いと言うほど酷くはないような……」という気分になります。不自然と間違いの間に明確な境界がないのは承知していますが。